# Is there any web app or script to import contacts using OAuth?

Tags: webapp-rec

We want to add **invite feature** to our site, so users can invite their friends.

Is there any web app or script that can import contacts from Gmail, Yahoo, Live, etc using OAuth, so we can send invite email to user's selected contacts?

<sub>Something like [free Tell a friend](http://www.freetellafriend.com/).</sub>

Comment: I want an option to set invite message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found [InviteBox](http://invitebox.com/). It's not self hosted but it has more options to customize. And is still in Beta phase, but you can make a request for beta invite.

Answer (score -1):

OpenID is a login service specification and does not specify anything about contacts. You're trying to use the wrong tool here.

### Longer explanation:

1. OpenID is used to identificate the user
2. When the user's identity is confirmed, Google logs you into Gmail
3. Once you are logged into gmail, you can fetch the user's contacts

As you see, OpenID has nothing to do with fetching contact data; it's merely a way to identify users. Once you are identified, you still need to use the different APIs that Google, Yahoo and so provide to fetch their contacts. OpenID does not help you with that.

### Edit: OAuth

I see that you changed your question from OpenID to OAuth. You're still stuck with the same problem: OAuth, like OpenID, has nothing to do with accessing contact data. It's about authorization.

As the OAuth website states:

> An open protocol to allow secure **API authorization** in a simple and standard method from desktop and web applications.

### Your question

You are looking for a standardized API to fetch contacts from remote servers. Each of the services (Yahoo, Google, Live, GMX) have their own APIs. There is nothing standardized. You need to implement it differently for each service.

Comment: You can login using OpenID to get your Gmail Contacts

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Take a look at this site: http://www.freetellafriend.com/ and try it, I want something like this

Comment: And I really thought that you wanted an answer to your question.

Comment: I want something self hosted with more options

Answer (score -1):

Try out the latest [Social Inviter](http://socialinviter.com) plugin where you can customize the "look and feel" of the page. The Social Inviter script imports contacts details such as name, emails, addresses, phone numbers, notes, birthday and websites. Completely painless and easy to integrate in your website.

Demo here: http://socialinviter.com/#!/contactimporter

Documentation: http://socialinviter.com/#!/cidoc

Get Trial key here: http://socialinviter.com/#!/trial

Interactive console: http://socialinviter.com/#!/console

[image]